# $\forall x,y,z \in \mathbb{R} (x\cdot 0 + y \cdot 0 + z \cdot 0=0) \to (x=y=z=0)$

Tags: real-analysis, predicate-logic

$\forall x,y,z \in \mathbb{R} (x\cdot 0 + y \cdot 0 + z \cdot 0=0) \to (x=y=z=0)$?? If is true, why? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Except the definition of the function $P(x, y, z)$ aren't you supposed to have some other condition? And what does this $P(x, y, z) = x = y = z = 0$ is supposed to mean at all? That $P$ would be equal to $x, y, z$.. It doesn't make sense. Please clarify.

Comment: @lnwvr, I correct my post.. thanks!

Comment: Your implication still does not make sense. Aren't you missing some quantifiers like $\forall, \exists$? You can't just leave the variables unbound since you won't be able to evaluate the formula. Don't you mean, for example, $\forall x \forall y \forall z(x . 0 + y . 0 + z . 0)\rightarrow (x=y=z=0)$

Comment: @lnwvr, yes.. I correct my post, excuse me!! thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $+$ and $\cdot$ mean usual addition and multiplication of real numbers, and if $0$ means the particular zero element of the reals, then the predicate $P(x,y,z)=0$ holds for any triple $(x,y,z).$ In that sense, this predicate does *not* mean the same as $x=y=z=0$, as the latter predicate is only true at $(0,0,0)$ and yours is true at any triple $(x,y,z).$

Edit: I should have used predicate notation for both. That is, $P(x,y,z)$ is the predicate $x\cdot 0 +y \cdot 0 + z \cdot 0=0$, and it happens that $P(x,y,z)$ holds for any choice of the variables $x,y,z$. And we can define $Q(x,y,z)$ to be the predicate $x=y=z=0$, so that only $Q(0,0,0)$ is true, while $Q$ is false for other choices like $Q(1,3,2).$ The relation is that if $Q$ holds then $P$ also holds, but not conversely. Note that the same effect as $P$ could be obtained by defining $P$ to be $x=x.$ This is also true for any triple $x,y,z.$

Comment: @coffemath, so Is implication true?

Comment: @Soviet, does every $(x,y,z)$ have the property that $x=0$ and $y=0$ and $z=0$? Its false.

Comment: @Soviet The implication *from* $x=y=z=0$ to $x \cdot 0 + y \cdot 0 + z \cdot 0 = 0$ is true, but your posted question asked about the other direction, the implication from $P$ to $Q$ as I just put into the "Edit" section at the end of my answer above. *That* direction of the implication is false.

Comment: @coffeemath, okok I understand.. thanks soo much!! :)

Comment: @Soviet No problem. These "logical relations" such as does this abstraction imply this other one can be confusing until one gets used to working with them.